# Styling in xampp is different then files on my desktop?

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

The weirdest thing in the world is happening to me, and I wanted to ask if anyone has heard of anything similiar to this, and any possible solution. My designer created a website, on his own computer. I implemented his css + html in my code, and I noticed everything was coming out a bit bigger on my website (eg menu was wider, top bar was larger, etc)
After playing around with this for over 3 hours, I decided to just Save the website the designer made to my Desktop. I did this, opened it in chrome, and it was exactly like I saw on the designers site. I then proceeded to copy past the website I saved into xampp- and lo and behold, everything was bigger, JUST like in MY website. I have quite literally no idea what is going on, the exact same files on my Desktop are showing up differently when I copy them into xampp.

Any idea whats going on?
Thanks!

EDIT: To make matters weirder, it appears the enlarging only happens in chrome...

Comment: I'll take a guess at it being 7 cookies instead of 5.

Comment: If you mean it's that I forgot to clear my cookies- I tried clearing all browsing data through the tools in chrome, as well as CTRL SHIFT R- didn't work

Comment: I'm saying that we need to see some code or something (screenshots/etc) to even be able to help you right now, because this question will only gather opinion based answers as nobody will be able to narrow down your issue. (**Side Question:** You sure your browser isn't zoomed in? Check by pressing `CTRL` + `0`)

Comment: I don't understand how this can be true but yes apparently I was zoomed in. I wasted 4 freaking hours of my time on this. I've been developing for over 5 years, I've never ever felt this dumb in my life

Comment: Happens to the best of us mate :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*`As per the comments`*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006196/styling-in-xampp-is-different-then-files-on-my-desktop?noredirect=1#comment38882364_25006196)

---

It's rather impossible to ensure that we can narrow down your issue without viewing any code or anything of the likes.
But first ensure that your browser is at proper standard settings.

Make sure you are zoomed out by pressing `CTRL` + `0` (*on windows*).

It could've also potentially have been that the stylesheet was missing something, but in this case it wasn't.