# Fatal error: Call to undefined function getRow() in PHPExcel export

Tags: php, export, export-to-excel, phpexcel

I'm new in PHPExcel library and this is my first experience. I'm trying to export MySQL data to Ms Excel by formatting before. I've implemented a procedure that simply formats headings of the table with bold fonts and saves them with all relevants data to the spreadsheet. However, when I run the procedure, it displays the following error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function getRow() in C:\Xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 182`

**Here is the PHP code:**

```
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php';

// create mysql query
$query_export = "SELECT * FROM `table1` ORDER BY `date` ASC";

// execute query
$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['mysqli'], $query_export) or die ("<b>Couldn't execute SQL query:</b> " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS['mysqli']));

try {
    $sheet = new PHPExcel();

    // set metadata
    $sheet->getProperties()->setCreator('www.example.com')
                           ->setLastModifiedBy('www.example.com')
                           ->setTitle('Report on Table')
                           ->setKeywords('report tables etc.');

    // set default settings
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setVertical(
            PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP);
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(
            PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setName('Calibri');
    $sheet->getDefaultStyle()->getFont()->setSize(12);

    // get reference to active spreadsheet in workbook
    $sheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $activeSheet = $sheet->getActiveSheet();

    // populate with data
    $row = getRow($result);    // line 182
    $colHeaders = array_keys($row);
    $col = 'A';
    $rownum = 1;

    // set column headings
    foreach ($colHeaders as $header) {
        $activeSheet->setCellValue($col . $rownum, $header);
        $activeSheet->getStyle($col . $rownum)->getFont()->setBold(true);
        $activeSheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
        $col++;
    }

    // populate individual cells with data
    do {
        $col = 'A';
        $rownum++;
        foreach ($row as $value) {
            $activeSheet->setCellValue($col++ . $rownum, $value);
        }
    } while ($row = getRow($result));

    // setting headers
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Export.xlsx');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');

    $writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheet, 'Excel2007');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}

// display error
if (isset($error)) {
    echo "<p>" .$error. "</p>";
}

// free resultset
mysqli_free_result($result);
// close db connection
$GLOBALS['mysqli']->close();
exit();
```

Any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The following tutorial is used to create above mentioned code:
[http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6MQQvBi-ks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6MQQvBi-ks#t=65)

Comment: `$sheet->getRow()` possibly?

Comment: `your db connection string->getRow();`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Makes me think of a cute little puppy crying because of library mix-ups. :-(

Comment: I'm like an 'ol dawg that likes new tricks @Darren I'm just a puppy in disguise ;) but have been dewormed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Luckily you won't forget something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25006508/2518525)! [but you'll be simly the best](http://freefunnydogpictures.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/siberian-husky-puppies-for_1400077651.jpg)

Comment: @Darren I'd look at all the possible angles. Not without being "there", one's answer can never be taken out of the equation ;)

Comment: Assuming `getRow()` is supposed to be retrieving data from a database, perhaps `$result->getRow()`? This isn't a PHPExcel issue, it's a basic coding issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to define getRow or use something like this:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: It's not SQL so this does not come close to answering OP's question.

Comment: So he's using mysqli functions just for fun?

Comment: His question is related to `PHPExcel` and the `getRow()` method.

Comment: Please read his code and his question. The error is from calling getRow on a mysqli result. He wants to use fetch row or he has more issues than he realizes.

Comment: @DanielWilliams as @Darren mentioned my question is related to `PHPExcel` and `getRow()` method. From SQL query point of view everything is ok i checked them several times.

Comment: @Dozent looking at your code, your only invocation of getRow is on a sql result. So either you want to call getRow on something else or you want the above fetch row function.

Comment: @Dozent - The `getRow()` method isn't related to PHPExcel at all unless you're trying to invoke the method for a cell (in which case, what cell, because you haven't any cell objects at this point).... if it isn't trying to retrieve data from the database, then what is `getRow()` supposed to be doing?